# Python logger does not print debug messages, even if logger.getEffectiveLevel() is DEBUG

Tags: python, python-logging

The following code changes the log level from INFO to DEBUG, and even though
logger.getEffectiveLevel() returns DEBUG, the debug message doesn't get logged,
as the output shows.

version of python: 3.10.12

---out.log---

```
log level 1: INFO
log level 2: DEBUG
```

Code

```
import logging
import logging.config

def test_change_log_level():
    logger = logging.Logger("my-logger", logging.INFO)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename="out.log")

    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    logger.debug("should not be logged ...")
    logger.info("log level 1: %s", logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.info("log level 2: %s", logging.getLevelName(logger.getEffectiveLevel()))
    logger.debug("debug level is effective")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    test_change_log_level()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects):

> Loggers should *NEVER* be instantiated directly, but always through the module-level function `logging.getLogger(name)`.

Secondly, the handler is not relevant to the problem, so here I've replaced it with a root handler.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='')

def test_change_log_level():
    logger = logging.getLogger("my-logger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    logger.debug("should not be logged ...")

    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logger.debug("debug level is effective")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_change_log_level()
```

Output:

```
debug level is effective
```

Comment: P.S. Check out [ask] for tips for future questions, like starting with your own research (namely, reading the docs yourself), and making a [mre] (namely, removing the handler, but also playing around with your code until you localize the problem to, ideally, a single line).